# return an associative array using laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

I want to fetch a post along with its associate images. My query returns results as follows:

**query**

```
$result =  DB::table('posts')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->join('post_images', 'post_images.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
            ->select('users.name', 'posts.*', 'post_images.image')
            ->where([
               'users.id' => 1,
               'posts.id' => 38
            ])
            ->get();
dd($result);
```

**output**

[image]

I want all images associated with the post populate as an associative array of single collection/result. For example for ID 38 instead of 2 result as above image i need as follows:

```
array:49 [▼
  0 => {#205 ▼
    +"name": "wahid"
    +"id": 38
    +"user_id": 1
    +"categories_id": 1
    +"body": "something !!"
    +"color": "LightGreen"
    +"mood": "Loved"
    +"created_at": "2017-08-07 01:15:48"
    +"updated_at": "2017-08-07 01:15:48"
    +"images" => array:3 [
        0 => 'image1.jpg'
        1 => 'image2.jpg'
        2 => 'image3.jpg'
    ]
  }
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to add `->groupBy('posts.id')->get();` and see

Comment: Do you use Eloquent models and relationships?

Comment: in case of complex query i prefer query builder. here i am not using models. @iArcadia

Comment: I searched but found no idea. I suppose you want to avoid using two database requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try to group by posts id :

```
$result =  DB::table('posts')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->join('post_images', 'post_images.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
            ->select('users.name', 'posts.*', 'post_images.image')
            ->where([
               'users.id' => 1,
               'posts.id' => 38
            ])
            ->groupBy('posts.id')
            ->get();
dd($result);
```

Comment: thanks@Maraboc it shows only one result. not others :(

Comment: What others ? you mean one image ?

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

use `->get()->toArray();`

```
$result =  DB::table('posts')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->join('post_images', 'post_images.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
            ->select('users.name', 'posts.*', 'post_images.image')
            ->where([
               'users.id' => 1,
               'posts.id' => 38
            ])
            ->get()->toArray();
dd($result);
```